# Erro no código Python - SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um jogo de futsal com POO, e fui fazer uma função fora da classe e no escopo global atribui o vetor `lista_team = []`, só que quando estou tentando rodar o estágio em que o código está, gera um erro, o que pode ser? Quero adicionar a resposta do `input` ao vetor, em cada posição.

```
lista_team.append() = input('Digite o nome do seu time: \n')
```

> ```
> File "C:\Python37\Scripts\futsal.py", line 45
>     lista_team.append() = input('Digite o nome do seu time: \n')
>     ^
> SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
> ```

Comment: É só passar o resultado do `input` como parâmetro de `append`: `lista_team.append(input('Digite o nome do seu time: \n'))`

Answer (score 2):

Quando você usa o sinal de igual o Python entende que você esta tentando declarar uma variável, e como você já deve saber, o "append" é um método do objeto "list".

**Ele funciona da seguinte maneira:**

```
lista_team = []
lista_team.append(input('digite o nome do seu time!\n'))
```

Comment: Faltou a função input

Comment: Entendi, obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode declarar o input e após inserir o resultado na lista.

```
lista_team = []
name_team = input('digite o nome do time')
lista_team.append(name_team)
```

Prefiro dessa forma pq vc pode acrescentar uma camada de validação de forma simples.

```
lista_team = []
name_team = input('digite o nome do time')
if <sua_verificção>:
    lista_team.append(name_team)
```

Comment: Entendi, obrigado !